# Nodejs: want to map domains to server

Tags: node.js

I have a webapp where I allow people to create sub-sites on my app server (ex:mysite.com/their-site). I want them to be able to point their domain to the sub-site on my app. Similar to how you attach a domain to a shared hosting server.

I'm not really sure how to go about this. Would appreciate it if anybody could enlighten me.

Comment: Are you pointing these at different Node.js instances?  Or all the same app?

Comment: What you mention in example is confusing: `mysite.com/their-site` would not be on a separate domain, it is a different route. You usually have domain like `domain.com` and subdomain like `mail.domain.com`. Do you want to redirect such requests or process them ?

Comment: @user568109 Sorry for the confusion. mysite.com/their-site would be their page on my application. They may have they own domain registered elsewhere which i would like the option for them to map to their page on my site.

Comment: @Brad this one application the multiple domains will point to

Comment: There's downsides to having one app that all domains resolve to - see second half of my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use something like [node http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/) you can run each of the separate sites on different local ports and then map the domain name back.  I use the http proxy but others love nginx.

For that to work, you'll need to add DNS entries resolving to the IP address that your reverse proxy is running on.  Then for example, the port 80 request will get mapped back to localhost:3000.

This allows for each app to run in isolation and in separate processes from the other sites.  They can't crash each other.  You also don't have namespace issues where both apps claim the same path.

My app.js for the http proxy looks like this:

```
var proxyPort = 80;
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var options = {
    router: {
        'localhost': '127.0.0.1:3000',
        'somesite.com': '127.0.0.1:3000',
        'othersite.com': '127.0.0.1:4000'
    }
};
console.log('Proxy Routing:');
console.log(options);
console.log();

var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options);
proxyServer.listen(proxyPort);
console.log('Proxy listening on port ' + proxyPort);
```

You can also route with paths.  See this: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/232

So more like your original request, you can do:

```
router: {
    'myhost.com/appA': '127.0.0.1:8080',
    'myhost.com/appB': '127.0.0.1:9090/appB',
    'myhost.com/appC': '127.0.0.1:9090/appC'
  }
};
```

Another option is to simply provide a route/page per customer and then it's simply a DNS problem.  You would setup DNS so that all domain names resolve to the one IP address your app runs on.  That has some downsides:

1. domain1.com/user1, domain1.com/user2, domain2.com/user1 and domain2.com/user2 would all work which you probably don't want.
2. Do you control all the code or do they supply code?  If it's user supplied code then you want some isolation so therefore separate apps.
3. You still likely need an http proxy to run on port 80 in linux and not run as sudo.

Comment: In my case I think I'm setting a domain to a route. So would something like this work out: 'user1domain.com': '127.0.0.1:9090/user1page'?

Comment: Also would this be the preferred method if I plan to have 100+ domains mapped to this application?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine.  A 100+ won't be a problem - of course it all depends on load of each domain and resource demands.  What's nice is the routing also means you could scale out to multiple boxes if ever needed.

Comment: Ok this is what ill try on my end. What should i have their registrar point to? do i need to have them change their name servers or something? also will sub-routes still work with their domain after the proxy? (ex: user1domain.com/account). Sorry never used any reverse proxies before.

Comment: They don't have to change name servers - but wherever their register points, to would need DNS edits.  If they want you to be able to manage it, then it may make it easier to manage if all entries on one DNS server/company.

Comment: I feel like i am still supposed to do something on the registrar side, thats where im still drawing a blank... Which dns settings are supposed to be changed on the registar??

Comment: The registrar points to your DNS name servers.  It says, if you want to resolve site.com, this DNS server can do it for you.

Comment: Your hosting company or cloud platform (azure, aws etc...) usually has domain name services and supply you name servers and a way to enter your own.  Of course you can run/host your own name server but that seems like a pain :)