# Setting up multiple node servers using Nginx without subdomains

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, reverse-proxy

I have been looking all over but haven't found a single person hosting multiple node sites on the same server without using subdomains. I want something like the following...

website.com/app1 -> 127.0.0.1:3000
website.com/app2 -> 127.0.0.1:9000

```
upstream node {
   server 127.0.0.1:3000;
   keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  webaddress.com;

    root /var/www/trucks/;

    location /livereload {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:35729;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /app1 {
        rewrite ^/app1/?(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        root /var/www/trucks;
}
```

I have even tried rewriting the request; however, that doesn't appear to be having any effect. If I remove /app1 it works correctly. The closest I have gotten is forwarding to multiple sites but then the local express routes are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working setup as follows:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name localhost;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `proxy_redirect` directive instead of `rewrite` ?
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect

Answer (score 0):

- Use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) as reverse proxy
- Use [connect-vhost](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html)
- or maybe you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070377/nodejs-want-to-map-domains-to-server)

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your configuration its that you are mixin regular http applications proxying with websockets application proxying. There is no need to use rewrite. Here is the simplest configuration I could come up with:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name _;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_set_header Host $host;

  location /node1 {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
  }
  location /node2 {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;
  }
}
```

I recommend you redding the websockets related documentation on nginx site:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html